# Insert query in php not working with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, insert

I am having some problems with insert query which is called from ajax. The ajax call comes back with success and I am able to see it with the changed html as noted below in the code under success:function(). I am not sure why the insert query in process.php is not working. dataString has the arguments correct (alert for dataString shows the right arguments) and my fields in database can take null values.

js code

```
  var dataString=$('#testimonials').serialize();

  alert (dataString);

  $.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    data: dataString,
    success:function() {
      $('#testimonials').html("<div id='message'></div>");
      $('#message').html("<h2>Your information has been submitted!</h2>")
      .append("<p>Thank you for your help and support.</p>")
      .hide()
      .fadeIn(1500, function() 
      {
        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' height='30' width='30'/>");
      });
   });
```

process.php file

```
    $company =mysql_escape_string($_POST('company'));
    $jobfunc = mysql_escape_string($_POST('jobfunc'));
    $location = mysql_escape_string($_POST('location'));
    $overall = mysql_escape_string($_POST('overall'));
    $detail = mysql_escape_string($_POST('detail'));
    $pros = mysql_escape_string($_POST('pros'));
    $cons = mysql_escape_string($_POST('cons'));
    $sr_mgmt = mysql_escape_string($_POST('sr_mgmt'));
    $submitted_by = mysql_escape_string($_POST('submitted_by'));
    $class = mysql_escape_string($_POST('classof'));
    $school = mysql_escape_string($_POST('school'));
    $anonymous = mysql_escape_string($_POST('anonymous'));      

    mysql_select_db($database_connTest, $connTest);

    $query_AddTestimonial = "INSERT into testimonials (company,job_function,location,overall,project_details,pros,cons,sr_mgmt,submitted_by,class,school,anonymous) VALUES ('$company','$jobfunc','$location','$overall','$detail','$pros','$cons','$sr_mgmt','$submitted_by','$class','$school','$anonymous')";
    $result_AddTestimonial = mysql_query($query_AddTestimonial) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You need to pass parameters from this URL `url: "process.php"` which you want to insert into your database.

Comment: I believe he is doing that via dataString.

Comment: What do you mean its not working .. are you having any error output ??? or its not inserting to the database ??

Comment: Baba, its not inserting to the database. Lion - As RPM mentioned, shouldn't the dataString take care of passing the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In the penultimate line when you create $query_AddTestimonial, the string you're creating isn't putting the php variables in because you're not telling it that they're variables. You can use the php variables like this:

```
$query_AddTestimonial = "INSERT into testimonials (company,job_function,location,overall,project_details,pros,cons,sr_mgmt,submitted_by,class,school,anonymous) VALUES ('{$company}','{$jobfunc}','{$location}','{$overall}','{$detail}','{$pros}','{$cons}','{$sr_mgmt}','{$submitted_by}','{$class}','{$school}','{$anonymous}')";
```

Comment: The second from last line (in the process.php file).

Comment: Ben, I tried using the variables the way you have defined it but still the record is not getting inserted into mySQL. Isn't $_POST taking care of assigning the values to the variables declared in process.php. For example, in $company = $_POST['company'], isn't $company the variable in this case which is assigned the value from $_POST['company']? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I just checked the insert statement by putting static values in the sql query and the insert works with the ajax calls. So the problem is with passing the parameters. I tried defining the parameters many ways but it doesnt work. Does anyone have any suggestions? So far I have tried defining it under $.ajax function as data: dataString and data: {company: 'Yahoo', jobfunc: 'operations' .... and data: {company : company_name, jobfunc : jobfunction) with variables defined for company_name and jobfunction with values assigned to them, but unfortunately none of these solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the way I was calling the variables. It should have been $_POST['company'] rather than $_POST('company'). Completely missed it (the square brackets for $_POST since its an array)